# 18.04 GNOME3 Shell bug: Dash doesn't return when waking up screen saver or unlocking the screen?

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver, dock

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buV5M.jpg)

So this happened to me before when using Ubuntu in the past. This has proven to be very annoying and the main reason I stopped using Ubuntu before. I've never been able to solve the issue so I'm hoping someone here can help.

The dock on the left hand side vanishes whenever my screensaver pops up, or whenever I lock my screen. The only way I seem to get it back is by logging out, or rebooting my computer.

I don't know how else to describe this issue so I hope between my post and the picture it's clear enough.

I just installed Ubuntu yesterday and have made no changes to the OS. The only programs I have installed are Android Studios, Steam, and Discord. However This issue has been a problem before any of these were installed so I highly doubt they are a part of the issue.

Comment: The dock doesn't show back up, that's my problem. The image should show what I'm talking about. Thanks you for replying.

Comment: It does not restore it. The only way I've found to restore it is to log out, or reboot. I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: OK. The Dash of the GNOME3 Shell of Ubuntu 18.04 does not return when you cursor over it after you've returned to the PC after the screensaver kicked in, or after you've unlocked the console after previously locking it. Documented as a GNOME3 bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1796265 but closed due to inactivity; please reopen it by running `ubuntu-bug gnome-shell` and documenting it

Comment: Correct. Once the screen locks, or the screen saver kicks in and I unlock my computer the Dash/Dock does not return at all. Even with my cursor over it nothing happens.

Comment: It was documented as a GNOME3 bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1796265 but closed due to inactivity; please reopen it by running `ubuntu-bug gnome-shell` and documenting it. Also, if you change to another desktop, or another Ubuntu flavour  https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours , you won't see this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll do just that!

Comment: Have you tried to change its position from left to right, down?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Let me know when you have this. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Answer (score 0):

Try different configuration options.

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock
```

Open `gnome-tweaks` and enable **Dash to dock**:
[image: tweaks window]

Open **Dash to dock** settings by gear icon clicking and change them.

[image: Dash to dock settings picture]

It is also interesting what will happen when you will not close this settings window while locking/unlocking your screen and changing settings with dock being absent.

Another workaround is to use budgie-desktop. You could also try lightdm instead of gdm3.

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work for me either.

Comment: Try budgie-desktop or lightdm instead of gdm3